# How to complie OpenBSD in src?

Tags: compiling, git, openbsd

Running on OpenBSD, I issue a:

```
git clone https://github.com/openbsd/src.git
```

then how can I compile all the OpenBSD binaries? Is there a "master" make file? I only need the binaries inside the src directory, not in place like /bin etc.

Answer (score 2):

Compiling OpenBSD's base system is described in the OpenBSD FAQ under the section [Building the System from Source](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq5.html).

It is assumed that you build the system with an OpenBSD system that is recent and that you have an up-to-date kernel installed and have read [the Following -current FAQ](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/current.html).

The "master" Makefile is the Makefile in the top of the `src` hierarchy.

Building the base system is not allowed with `DESTDIR` set (this is disallowed in the main Makefile), so you can't really build the system and install in an alternate location that way, and the `install` target is built by default.

I would suggest building the base system in a chroot (which I haven't tried) or in a virtual machine.